# discord.py SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I got an error in the whole code below.
I would like to seek help with the error.
Can I ask for help by looking at the code below?

```
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason: typing.Optional[str] = "사유 없음."):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    author = ctx.message.author
    embed = None
    ch = bot.get_channel(id=772349649553850368)

    mesge = await ctx.send("차단을 시킬까요?")
    await mesge.add_reaction('✅')
    await mesge.add_reaction('❌')
        
    def check1(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "✅"

        try:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 30.0, check = check1)
            embed = discord.Embed(title="종합게임 커뮤니티 제재내역 - 차단", description=f'담당자 : {author.mention} \n대상자 : {member.mention} \n제재사유 : {reason} \n\n위와 같은 사유로 인해 제재처리 되었습니다.', color=0xff0000)
            embed.set_author(name=f"{str(member)}님을 서버에서 영구적으로 차단했어요.", icon_url=member.avatar_url_as(static_format='png', size=2048))
            embed.set_footer(text=f'처리 시각 - {str(now.year)} 년 {str(now.month)} 월 {str(now.day)} 일 | {str(now.hour)} 시 {str(now.minute)} 분 {str(now.second)}초 - 담당자 : {author.display_name}')
            await ch.send(embed=embed)
            await member.send(embed=embed)
            await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=f'사유 : {reason}  -  담당자 : {author.display_name}')
    
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout")
    
    def check2(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "❌"

        try:
            reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 30.0, check = check2)
            await ctx.send("취소되었다")
        
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout")
```

The following error appears in the above code.

```
reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 30.0, check = check1)
                     ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
```

If you know how to fix it, please help.

I used a translator.

Comment: Have you tried changing `def check1` to `async def check1` and `def check2` to `async def check2`?  I haven't done much with async/await, but that is what I would try first as it seems to be what the error message is suggesting you do.

Comment: I think its identation. Notice that the try block is inside the function `check1` ... you want to dedent that code so that it is in `ban`.

Comment: The same for `check2`. you put the following try inside the function when it should be dedented 4 spaces to the left so that it is part of the parent function.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses identation to identify code blocks. In your code, you placed the `await` call inside of the non-async function `check1`. Here is an example of the same problem:

```
async def foo():

    def check1():
        return True
        
        baz = await bar() # improperly indented and in fact can never
                          # run because it is after the function `return`
```

The fix is to move the code outside of `check1`. It should align with the "def" statement above.

```
async def foo():

    def check1():
        return True
        
    baz = await bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with indentation after both checks.

I have added `# ---- here ----` So that you know where to end the `check`

```py
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason: typing.Optional[str] = "사유 없음."):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    author = ctx.message.author
    embed = None
    ch = bot.get_channel(id=772349649553850368)

    mesge = await ctx.send("차단을 시킬까요?")
    await mesge.add_reaction('✅')
    await mesge.add_reaction('❌')
        
    def check1(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "✅"
    
    # ---- here ----
    
    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 30.0, check = check1)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="종합게임 커뮤니티 제재내역 - 차단", description=f'담당자 : {author.mention} \n대상자 : {member.mention} \n제재사유 : {reason} \n\n위와 같은 사유로 인해 제재처리 되었습니다.', color=0xff0000)
        embed.set_author(name=f"{str(member)}님을 서버에서 영구적으로 차단했어요.", icon_url=member.avatar_url_as(static_format='png', size=2048))
        embed.set_footer(text=f'처리 시각 - {str(now.year)} 년 {str(now.month)} 월 {str(now.day)} 일 | {str(now.hour)} 시 {str(now.minute)} 분 {str(now.second)}초 - 담당자 : {author.display_name}')
        await ch.send(embed=embed)
        await member.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=f'사유 : {reason}  -  담당자 : {author.display_name}')

    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout")
    
    def check2(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == "❌"
    # ---- here ----
    
    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout = 30.0, check = check2)
        await ctx.send("취소되었다")
    
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout")
```

Comment: neither `check1` nor `check2` need to be `async`. They are simple logic checks and do not block.

Comment: I see it now i thought the `try` was outside of it,

Comment: I was caught by that at first too. Puzzled about why you'd do a `try` block _after_ a return.